# How to change old electrical box with conduits

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am working on removing an old wall electrical box, as it is too small for a dimmer, and replace it with a new bigger blue colour box. Is it a good idea?

I checked that wires in the old box come through the conduit and I would need to remove the [connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GATQEU).

I think removing the connector would be fine but the I am worried about the conduit being so close to the new box and how wires would be entering the new plastic blue box?

Any thought on that?

Do I need to cut the conduit a little bit for a free movement of wires as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Do not use a "blue box" for conduits. nearly all are not made correctly for use with conduit, and they are inferior to steel boxes that are made for use with conduit. HOWEVER, the mere fact that you HAVE conduit raises a significant possibility that your LAHJ may take a dim view of doing your own electrical work - most occupancies that require conduit are ones where an electrician is required, as well, due to risk to other people. And no, you cannot remove the connectors and leave the conduits hanging near the improper box.

Comment: The connector that you linked to in your question is not an electrical conduit connector. So it is highly doubtful that you would be removing such connector when conduit is in use. Also note that the pictured connector is one for securing jacketed cable to an electrical box. The wires currently inside the conduit are almost certain to NOT be a jacketed cable so you would not even be using that connector at a new box with the existing wires.

Comment: Either the "connector" that you currently have is not quite the one you pictured, or the "conduit" that you currently have is not really a conduit.  A photo of your actual box would be useful and also a photo or description of any other constraints on where the new bigger box would go.   Specifically: why can't you replace the existing box with a bigger one of the same material and type as the current one using the same hardware, whatever that may be, as the current one?  If something is stopping you from doing that, it would be useful to see the problem.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Is this an apartment? Multi story building? Electrical code changes with location and type of building a plastic box may be a code violation.

Comment: You NEED a metal box, since the metal conduit you already have **is relying on the metal box for its grounding path**.  If you are hellbound and determined to switch to plastic (probably a Code violation in your town), then you will need to add a green ground wire to every pipe.  This is the wrong way to do that thing; the right way is to skill up on metal conduit and use a bigger metal box.   By the way if you like big boxes, use a 4-11/16" square deep box with a 1-gang or 2-gang mud ring - you will never want for box space!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, thank you. I understood my mistake. I shall go for a larger metal box and find the connector that joins the metal conduit to the metal box. Thank you so much. I hope I will be easily able to remove the conduit from the box without damaging the wall much.